# What's the difference between "." and "#" in CSS and how to choose to use?

Tags: css

I'm learning in CSS, I am really confused when to use `.`(dot) and when to use `#` in CSS file. Sometimes I really wondered which one I should use.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### #You are .Human

While there are many humans, there is only one *you*. As such, `.` is for classes, which can appear over and over in a document. `#` is for IDs, which are unique to a document.

```
<div class="firstname" id="personA">
    <p class="lastname">Sampson</p>
</div>

<div class="firstname" id="personB">
    <p class="lastname">Sampson</p>
</div>
```

Note the unique identifier for both `div`, `personA` and `personB`. However both elements have classes in common, such as `.firstname`, and `.lastname`.

#### Professional Examples

You can see how these are used out in the wild by looking at tools like Modernizr. This feature-detection tool assists you by adding classes to the `<html>` element that inform you as to what the device or browser is capable of:

```
<html lang="en" dir="ltr" 
      id="modernizrcom" 
      class="js no-touch postmessage history multiplebgs boxshadow...">
```

Here we see the one unique value for the `<html>` element, `#modernizrcom`. Following, a series of classes that give more general info about the element. This is a clear example of how an element can have only one id, but many classes.

#### Careful with those IDs!

Because these values are *completely unique*, they can cause you to paint yourself into a corner at times. It's worth reading [*Disallow IDs in Selectors*](https://github.com/stubbornella/csslint/wiki/Disallow-IDs-in-selectors) to know more about the potential issues with using IDs in your selectors.

Answer (score 3):

The # is used for the id of an element and . is used for classes of an element. In a HTML document, an id is unique (there should only be one element with that id) while classes can occur multiple times.

```
<div id="content" class="shade light">
</div>
```

You can now do:

```
#content { border: solid 1px black; }
```

to add styling to that particular div element. But you can also do:

```
.light { background-color: #eeeeee; }
```

The difference is that the latter will apply that background color to all elements with that class (i.e., all elements with the class `light` while the first CSS statement will only add styling to the element with the id `content`).

Answer (score 0):

a dot (.) represents a class, a hash (#) represents an id.

There is more to it, but this is the gist:

An id (#myID) should be used when you only intend to use that selector **once**

A class (.myClass) should be used to create a reusable piece of styling code (e.g. to make text blue)

Answer (score 0):

**. is represent class**

**# is represent ID(but used only once in a page)**

*always the id is having the first priority in the race.*

**ex:**

**in the style**

```
.alignmeleft{float:left;}
#alignmeright{float:right;}
```

**in the html:**

```
<div class="alignmeleft" id="alignmeright">
<!--div content-->
</div>
```

**OUTPUT**

THE DIV WILL ALIGNED RIGHSIDE